# CRM 2011 - Form onload, transfer field data to entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I've set up contacts in leads successfully but when a user adds a new contact it wont auto fill in the parent lead field i created to link the contact to the lead.

Does anyone one know what script i could use onload that will auto fill a filed on the lead called Parent Lead. It needs to update the contact field with the leads primary account.

Hope that makes sense.

At the moment the user has to find the lead through the custom lookup field.

Comment: What way is your relationship? usually a contact/account would have many leads so one to many!

Answer (score 0):

Check your relationship ... 1to1, 1tomany, manytomany?

here is the code to populate a lookup field anyway:

```js
 var value = new Array();
 value[0] = new Object();
 value[0].id = idValue;
 value[0].name = textValue;
 value[0].entityType = typeValue;

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("fieldName").setValue(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard.

I basically created the lookups in Lead and contact.

What do you suggest i do, could i link it through a N:N

Ideally when i contact lookup is used on a lead i want it to automatically have the lead name populated as the contact form opens.

Comment: Sounds like you want to add a subgrid on contacts form that displays open leads that are regarding that contact? as the usual set up is that one contact can have many leads open!?

Comment: If that's the case just customize the form click insert tab & select subgrid set entity as lead(regarding)

Comment: sorry don't think i've made myself clear. I have leads that have contacts linked to them. When a user wants to link a contact they click on the lookup field and then they click NEW and create a contact. At this point they have to manually select the contact through the parent lead lookup field. Is there a way for CRM to automatically populate that field. It works for contacts in Accounts that is built in to the system.

Comment: sounds like you would need to use an OnCreate of contact plugin or custom workflow activity & use the logic that determines which contact you populate that look up field with.